# Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function with the property that there exits two sequence $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ such that

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function with the property that there exits two sequences $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ such that

$f(b_n)\to \infty$ and $f(c_n)\to -\infty $

Now I want to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}||b_n||\to\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}||c_n||\to\infty$

and  I want to show that $k>1$ there exists some $(a_n)\in\mathbb R^k$ such that $f(a_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $||a_n||\to \infty$

My work for the  $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}||b_n||\to\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}||c_n||\to\infty$

Assume not so  $||b_n||\to b\in \mathbb R$ and similar for $c_n$, $||c_n||\to c\in \mathbb R$

so since $||.||$ is a continuous function so $b_n\to \vec b\in\mathbb R^n$ and $c_n\to \vec c\in\mathbb R^n$ so since $f$ is continuous.

$$f(b_n)\to f(\vec b)\in\mathbb R$$ so it cannot be infinity. How to do it properly and can you give me a hint about second question I am stuck.$n>1$ there exists some $(a_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $f(a_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $||a_n||\to \infty$

Comment: $x\in \mathbb R^n$ what is the a_n's?

Comment: okey but how about $R^k$ if $k>1$ I dont understand that your example is from $R$ not the $R^k$ if $k>1$ right?

Comment: I see, I got confused by the use of $n$ for both $a_n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. Sorry for that. Please edit the question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. ;)

Comment: For the second part I tried to use generalized intermediate value theorem for R^n but didnot work, Can you gıve me counterexample for R or R^k , k>1

Comment: There is no counter example for $k>1$ see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $lim_n\|b_n\|$ is not $\infty$, there exists $C$ such that for every $n$, there exists $p_n>n$ with $\|b_n\|<C$.  Let $B(0,C)$ be the closed ball of radius $f(B,0,C))$, since $f$ is continuous, $f(B(0,C))$ is compact  and bounded, and contained in $[-P,P]$. Since $lim_nf(b_n)=\infty$,  there exists $n_P$ such that $n>n_R$ implies that $|f(b_n)|>P$. Contradiction.

Comment: This only answers the first part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Every continuous function reaches its maximum (resp. minimum) on every compact subset.
So, if $b_n$ is bounded in norm then, then we must have also $f(b_n)$ bounded in norm.

For the second part, suppose we have two sequences $\left( a_{n}\right)
_{n\geq 0}$ and $\left( b_{n}\right) _{n\geq 0}$ such that $\lim \left\Vert
a_{n}\right\Vert =\lim \left\Vert a_{n}\right\Vert =+\infty $ and $\lim
f\left( a_{n}\right) =-\lim f$ $\left( b_{n}\right) =+\infty $. Without loss
of generality we can take $f\left( a_{n}\right) $ and $-f\left( b_{n}\right) 
$ positive for every $n\geq 0$.

It is possible to take a sequence of curves $\left( S_{n}\right) _{n\geq 0}\ 
$such that $S_{n}$ joins $a_{n}$ to $b_{n}$ and for every $x\in S_{n}$ we
have,$\left\Vert x\right\Vert \geq \min (\left\Vert a_{n}\right\Vert
,\left\Vert b_{n}\right\Vert )$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $S_{n}$,  $f\left( a_{n}\right) >0$ and $f\left(
b_{n}\right) <0$ for every $n\geq 0$, we have a point $c_{n}\in S_{n}$ such
that $f(c_{n})=0$ and $\left\Vert c_{n}\right\Vert \geq \min (\left\Vert
a_{n}\right\Vert ,\left\Vert b_{n}\right\Vert )$.

Now it is easy to check that $\lim \left\Vert c_{n}\right\Vert =\infty $.

Comment: @nicomezi take a look now

Comment: I am not sure you did so there is no accusation behind this comment but since I have strong doubts, here is an advice : giving credit or citing is a much better pratice than discreet copying in hope that no one will see it. Providing full answers is not mandatory, but be clear about what you can answer and explain fully and what you cannot. If you found that by yourself, dont mind this comment and good job to you.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already give good arguments for the $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ part.
I will answer the $(a_n)$ part.

Let $\Gamma_n$ a path between $b_n$ and $c_n$ such that its smallest point is greater than $\frac 1 2 \min (b_n,c_n)$ in norm. Just pick a path between $b_n$ and $c_n$ outside the ball centered at $0$ with radius $\frac 1 2 \min (b_n,c_n)$ (which is always possible for $k \ge 2$ since we still have a connected space after removing this ball). Define $g_n$ the restriction of $f$ over this path, by the intermediate value theorem over $g_n$, we can find $a_n \in \Gamma_n$ such that $f(a_n) =0$.

By construction $ \|a_n\| \ge \frac 1 2 \min (b_n,c_n)$ and we conclude.